# Is there a function like C's !kbhit() in r to stop a loop?

Tags: c, r

Couldn't find anything through search but still not sure this isn't a duplicate as it seems to be a pretty basic question... but is there a similar function in R to C's `while (!kbhit())` to stop a loop when a key is pressed?

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen when a key is pressed. Normally it is sufficient to interrupt R which GUIs and IDEs offer keyboard short-cuts for. And you shouldn't need a `while` loop in efficient R code.

Comment: This is for a script not meant to be run from a GUI or IDE... It is to be set up to running perpetually from unix command prompt while the machine is not to be disturbed... when someone wants to stop it, he/she should be able to do so quickly by hitting any key on the keyboard...

Comment: This seems like it's outside the typical use case of R... you might just want to just wrap your application in C or python or something that is more used for daemons like this

Comment: I agree, don't loop in R. Use something like bash to call an R script in a loop. You might be interested in [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html).

Comment: Cool thanks... I suppose there is no directly equivalent function in R...

Comment: For the record, kbhit was an old, non-standard MS DOS function in Borland compilers which read stdin without waiting for the user to press enter after input.